# Assigning Event Listener to Dynamically Created HTML Button in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a web form with a dynamic amount of buttons on a page. The page is going to be used as a check sheet with two buttons for each label (one for good, one for no good). I am looking to attach an event listener to each button as they are added to the form. I have tried several different ways and searched all over, but have been unable to find anything that works. All suggestions welcome!

```
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    Response.Write("<tr style='height:60px'>")
    Response.Write("<td style='text-align:left; width:60%;'>")
    Response.Write("<label ID='lbl" & i & "' style='font-size:40px;'>" & ds.Tables("Issues").Rows(i).Item("Issue") & "</label>")
    Response.Write("</td>")
    Response.Write("<td style='text-align:left; width:20%'>")
    Response.Write("<button ID='btnOK" & i & "' style='font-size:25px; width:100%; height:100%;' type='button'>OK</button>")
    Response.Write("</td>")
    Response.Write("<td style='text-align:left; width:20%'>")
    Response.Write("<button ID='btnNG" & i & "' style='font-size:25px; width:100%; height:100%;' type='button'>N/G</button>")
    Response.Write("</td>")
    Response.Write("</tr>")

    Dim btnOK As Button = FindControl("btnOK" & i)
    Dim btnNG As Button = FindControl("btnNG" & i)

    'AddHandler btnOK.Click, AddressOf Me.btnOK_Click
Next
```

Currently with this code, the `FindControl` function returns nothing.

Comment: Looks like using a repeater could do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't created any dynamic buttons, just a string of text you write to the client. Therefore your `FindControl` will never work, as is assigning an event listener.

You create buttons dynamically like this:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.ID = "Button1";
button.Text = "ClickMe";
//attach event
button.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
```

VB

```
Dim button As Button = New Button
button.ID = "Button1"
button.Text = "ClickMe"
//attach event
AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf Me.Button1_Click

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button)
```

ASPX page example

```
<table>
    <tr style="height: 60px">
        <td>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Dynamically created Controls need to be created on every page load, that includes a `PostBack`.

More info here: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamic-Controls-Made-Easy-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find html buttons with server side code. This is impossible.
You should create all controls with server-side code. 
I wrote a c# iplementation of server side I'm not good at vb.

```
    Table tbl = new Table();
    TableRow tr = null;
    TableCell cell = null;

    int rows = dt.Rows.Count;
    int cols = dt.Columns.Count;


    TableHeaderRow htr = new TableHeaderRow();
    TableHeaderCell hcell = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        hcell = new TableHeaderCell();
        hcell.Text = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.ToString();
        htr.Cells.Add(hcell);

    }
    tbl.Rows.Add(htr);


    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
        tr = new TableRow();
        for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++)
        {
            cell = new TableCell();
            cell.Text = dt.Rows[j][k].ToString();
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.ID = "btnOK" + j;
            cell.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.onclick = eventHandler //Handler comes here
            tr.Cells.Add(cell);

        }
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
    }

    yourHtmlDiv.controls.add(table);
```